# Why is the window shown for a moment?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a WPF project in C#.

A SubWindow is created in the main window. Also, a LogWindow is created.

As shown, I hide mainWindow and subWindow:

```
SubWindow subWindow = new SubWindow();
LoginWindow loginWindow;
void MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   subWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
   this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

   loginWindow = new LoginWindow();
   loginWindow.Show();
}
```

There is a problem here.

loginWindow is visible, but mainWindow and subWindow are shown momentarily. I do not want them to appear, even for a short moment.

Comment: Change the visibility before `InitializeComponent` and do the same thing on your subwindow.

Comment: The same thing happens.

Comment: Hmm it works for me.

Comment: perhaps,Is this a rendering issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remove StartupUri line in App.xaml**, then move your code into App.xaml.cs making use of overriding OnStartup

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow()
    {
        Visibility = Visibility.Hidden
    };

    SubWindow subWindow = new SubWindow()
    {
        Visibility = Visibility.Hidden
    };

    LoginWindow loginWindow = new LoginWindow();

    loginWindow.Show();

    base.OnStartup(e);
}
```

Comment: MainWindow can't be shown if you remove StartupUri and don't have any `mainWindow.Show()` since nothing is calling it.

Comment: If it is created without calling show(), it is shown momently

Comment: This would basically be my answer and it should definitely work. Maybe highlight the `StartupUri` part a bit to make sure it's not skipped.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not in this code.
I duplicated this code and ran the Solution.
The problem you described does not reproduce.
Only LoginWindow is displayed without flickering other windows.

If you can, then reproduce the problem in a simple example Solution.
And put it on GitHub or in the archive to run it and understand the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Main Window's visibility attribute to hidden by default in you XAML file.

```
Visibility="Hidden"
```

This might fix your issue, as the window will never appear at first place.
You can then make it visible in your code whenever required.